# Check subset using either string or array in Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, impala

I have a table like this

```
 col
-----
 A,B
```

The `col` could be string with comma or array. I have flexibility on the storage.

How to check of `col` is a subset of either another string or array variable? For example:

`B,A` --> `TRUE` (order doesn't matter)

`A,D,B` --> `TRUE` (other item in between)

`A,D,C` --> `FALSE` (missing `B`)

I have flexibility on the type. The variable is something I cannot store in a table.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion for Impala only (no Hive).

Thanks

Comment: Never, ever, even consider storing sets of data as comma separated lists.  Normalise the structure, or use an array as you suggest.  But using comma separated strings in any database should be punishable by monty-python...

Comment: @MatBailie it's enterprise design where LDAP info stored in a column. I could make it a separate table if needed. But I don't have control of the variable component because again it's from LDAP being brought in "live" (not saved in table as cache).

Comment: I don't have access to Impala right now.  How do you select out each row of the array variable?  For example `SELECT * FROM yourTable, YourTable.col` would expand the array column out into new rows.  What's the syntax for doing that with a variable?  *(Once that's done I can show you the standard SQL approach.)*

Comment: No the variable is a fixed string, not from another table.

Comment: The variable can't be an array?

Comment: It's basically a parsed string directly into SQL statement. So if there is a way to make it array like Hive array('A','B') then sure...

Comment: I think you can remove the hive TaG from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not pretty method, but perhaps a starting point...

Assuming a table with a unique identifier column `id` and an `array<string>` column `col`, and a string variable with `','` as a separator *(and no occurrences of escaped `'\,'`)*...

```
SELECT
  yourTable.id
FROM
  yourTable,
  yourTable.col
GROUP BY
  yourTable.id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN find_in_set(col.item, ${VAR:yourString}) > 0 THEN col.item END)
  =
  LENGTH(regexp_replace(${VAR:yourString},'[^,]',''))+1
```

Basically...

- Expand the arrays in your table, to one row per array item.
- Check if each item exists in your string.
- Aggregate back up to count how many of the items were found in the string.
- Check that the number of items found is the same as the number of items in the string

The `COUNT(DISTINCT <CASE>)` copes with arrays like `{'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'}`.

Without expanding the string to an array or table *(which I don't know how to do)* you're dependent on the items in the string being unique.  *(Because I'm just counting commas in the string to find out how many items there are...)*

Comment: This is very creative. Thank you!